# Django - Select many instances/objects from a list and store them in a session to pay

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-models, django-views

i have built a simple ecommerce website where you can put many single items (one by one) in a session and then you can pay them.

My plan is that i can select/choose many instances/objects from a listview at one time and display them all at once in a session (cart).

I just want to kindly ask you how i can start that, not with code examples.

- How has to look the view ( it has to be an ajax view) ? no experience in ajax
- Are there any kind of django packages for that problem?
- I need to serialize my data for that ?

I would love that you guys put my research in right direction, then I would try myself out to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Django's session acts like a dictionary so you can build views that can be AJAX/ non-AJAX doesn't matter (preferably AJAX) to add/remove the item from your cart, and store your product's information in the session and then mark it as modified so it gets saved.

You can build a simple class that abstracts this away for eg.

```
class Cart:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        self.cart = self.session.setdefault('cart', {})

    def add_item(data):
        # your business login
        self.cart[data['product_id']] = data['id']
        self.session.modified = True
```

About serializing data, just do an AJAX call to your endpoint and fetch the data from request.

Comment: This wont solve the problem to select many products of a list at the same and add them add the same time to sessions (select many at once/one time)?